# How to export dataframe into excel with formatting in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two columns in my dataframe with date values.

when I am exporting it into xlsx format, columns values displaying with the date and time format both.

df = [image]

## Export data into excel file

df.to_excel(r'D:\Users\Desktop\CPS.xlsx',index=False)

Date value showing up with time format after exporting into xlsx format:
[image]

I just need to export it as it is. the only date should be displayed.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your dataframe and the command you used to export it ?

Comment: I paste my dataframe and excel file display image, can you please check and suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to export your DataFrame as a csv with

```
df.to_csv('D:\Users\Desktop\CPS.csv', index=False)
```

And then to import this csv file into Excel. I think that when importing the file, Excel will ask if you want to convert the text to date format. You just have to answer no to that question.

It worked for me on Google Sheets but I don't have Excel to test it.

Comment: this solution works for me but as per requirement, I have to export in xlsx format only.